# Wordpress Postname permalink doesn't work on localhost (xampp)

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, localhost

I don't know why but in localhost (xampp) when I choose post name in permalink I can't create a post (it shows an error about JSON ) and Elementor won't load, and I get this error below lots of time when I work on pages.
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.8

Everything is up to date , and php v is 7 .

Comment: Did you make sure that WordPress generated the .htaccess file correctly?

Answer (score -1):

Is mod_rewrite active? Check your PHP infos with phpinfo();
The .htacces-file should have this content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And how does your Apache .conf-file look like?